# Multiple Public IP's in One Network

Tags: networking, routing, nat, wide-area-network, mikrotik

I have Internet connection from ISP and got Static IP pool of 8 IP's with 5 Useful IP's...

Now I want to establish following network

ISP -> Mikrotik Router -> Switch ===> Web Servers & LAN

Now My Web Servers Uses all four IP's and One Live IP will be configured in Mikrotik Router.

My Question is what is correct way of Making all Servers accessable via assigned static public IP's and also want to USE LAN with private IP's.

Should I go with NAT, PAT or PORT Forwarding or there is any other better technique and how to do it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "correct" solution is to configure your router with the public IP addresses and use 1:1 NAT so web traffic entering the network is properly translated to the private IP addresses of your web server.

The other "correct" way to do this is to place your web servers in a DMZ.

Comment: And unless there is a specific reason for each web server to have their own public address, then run haproxy or something in front to load balance, and use only one address and have the others for different purposes.